# ShareTarget overrides RequestedTheme [Windows 10 UWP]

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

today I found some weird behavior. In my Windows 10 UWP app I give user option to set AppTheme (Light/Dark). I'm setting it in App constructor as it's the only place where it can be done. Everything was fine before I try to share photo from Photos app. My program supports share target so it's easy. BUT! When I launch app in ShareTarget mode I get phone default AppTheme despite the fact that in my constructor I change it.
When I enter the same page (ChooseFolderPage) from within the app, there is no problem with Theme.
All code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Aenw8GjU
As bonus I can add that I wanted to go around the problem and I set RequestedTheme on that ChooseFolderPage again - only BottomAppBar was changed...
This problem can be recreated on PC and Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a bug in the UWP runtime. When your apllication uses mutliple windows only the main window uses the Theme you have setted in your App constructor. Every other window (in your case the share window) are igonring the setting.

The problem only occures when the ApplicationTheme is setted in the App constructor. When the ApplicationTheme is setted in the Xaml every thing works fine.

current forum entry:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/402f848d-05b3-42ce-9692-b61da0c89e17/uwpwinrt-new-viewwindow-does-not-inherit-apprequestedtheme?forum=wpdevelop